# Relationship between the 'relevant states' and the states that can be generated by a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, many-body, tensor-network

In the huge quantum state space, for example n-qubit space has a state number as $2^{2^n}$, usually we are interested in two different kinds of 'physical' states.

Set 1: The relevant state which is defined as the ground/low energy states of a gapped local Hamiltonian, which is believed can be represented efficiently by [tensor networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164).

and

Set 2. The states that can be generated by a finite depth local quantum circuit from a product state. These states can be represented efficiently by quantum circuit models and deep Boltzmann machines as well.

They are both regarded as an exponentially small subset of the complete quantum state space. But they ARE different since not all the relevant states can be generated by a finite depth quantum circuit w.r.t. the qubit number n(such as the simple Toric code).

Now we need a bridge to connect them.

1. What's their relationship? Is Set 2 a subset of Set 1? Or they have a more complicated relationship?
2. Can all the Set 1 states be represented efficiently by DBM? In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05039) it's claimed that Set 1 states can be represented efficiently by DBM. But this conclusion is based on the the assumption that Set 1 can be efficiently represented by tensor networks. Can any body help to give a proof that Set 1 can be represented by tensor networks?

Can anyone help to clarify their relationship?

Comment: I don't know how to answer in full, but regarding the second point, have you seen the recent paper by Glasser et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04045)? They show that the representation obtained with DBMs is basically equivalent to some classes of tensor network states. If this shows that states representable by DBMs are also tensor network states, and these are low energy states of gapped local Hamiltonians, doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: by the way, this may be trivial, but how do you see that the states that can be generated by a finite depth local quantum circuit can all be represented by DBMs?

Comment: @glS  It means all states that can be efficiently represented by quantum circuits can also be represented by DBM. But quantum circuit is physical, which means if a state can be efficiently represented by a QC, then we can generate it. This is not the case of DBM.